# How do you say a "quote" as in a "quote from a author"

Tags: vocabulary

Does anyone know how to say "a quote" as in a quote from an author/book/piece of writing? 
Do people say 引号， 引文， 引用？

Thanks so much！

Comment: Not an authoritative answer, but looking on line you see 引号 is used for quote marks, while 引文 most often means a citation and not necessarily a quote from the cited source, and 引用 can be just a citation but is often an actual quote.  See for example http://baike.baidu.com/view/5976.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

引号  quotation mark

引文  quoted passage (usually in written format, rather than verbal format)

引用  to quote from some place

As a result, "quote from an author" should be "作者的引文", which is the only grammatically correct choice among the three words. However, it seems to be very unnatural for native Chinese speaker. The more native expression should be "作者曾说过" (the author has said).

Answer (score 0):

It can come in many forms:

> 孔子曾经说过：“逝者如斯夫。” As Confucius once said...
>
> 引用前主席的一句话：“你们啊，就是思想太简单，有时候幼稚的不行！” To quote the ex-chairman...
>
> 简·奥斯汀在《傲慢与偏见》里写道：年轻土豪都是急着要找老婆的。—— As Jane Austin wrote in her Pride and Prejudice...